# How to implement recyclerView(cardView) expandable item?

Tags: android

I want to implement something like this without using any third pary libraries. I've found only this link:

http://cjainewbw.blogspot.ru/2015/08/android-recyclerview-multi-selection.html

But I'm curious is there any other (maybe native way) to implement such a behavior?

[image]

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-behavior
link for

Comment: Have you made it?

Comment: Don't remember, by try to use visibility option to show/hide expandable part

Comment: update?? also need this